# How to (and where) install/upgrade pip for Python?

Tags: python

I plan on using python in the LiClipse IDE to play around with AI. However i require a few libraries. The libraries can be installed with pip. They mention the commands to install and upgrade pip(e.g. python -m pip install -U pip), however I am not sure where I should write this command anymore because it does not work in either the CMD or python shell.

Is there any condition while using these commands I should think about?

Thank you

Comment: What does the `cmd` say when you run this command?

Answer (score 0):

open cmd

goto the D:\python\Scripts(Your Installation directory)

Run The Command  pip install -U pip